# javascriptのFileAPIで読み込み途中のデータを取得することは可能ですか？

Tags: javascript, html5

ブラウザ上で、クライアントPCに保存されている点群データを操作をしようと考えています。

FileAPIで取得したfileオブジェクトを、FileReaderで読み込むことができることはわかりました。

ここからが質問なのですが、FileReaderで読み込んでいるデータを、途中で読み込み処理を停止して、停止した所までのデータを取得・操作することは可能でしょうか？

利用ケースとしては、点群データのヘッダー情報のみが必要で、全部を読み込む必要がなく、少しでも読み込み時間を短くしたいと思っています。全部を読み込んでから操作すればいいのですが、点群データは数10GBを平気で超えることもあり、読み込みに時間がかかるのがボトルネックとなっています。

サンプルコード

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onprogress = function( event ) {
    if ( event.loaded > 1000000 ) {
        fileReader.abort();
    }
}

fileReader.onabort = function( event ) {
    // 候補１：ここで途中まで読み込んだArraybufferを取得したい

    // 途中まで読み込んだ点群データを操作する処理を記述

}

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer( fileObj );
```

Answer (score 4):

残念ながら、 `FileReader` ではご希望の動作はできません。しかし、 `File` オブジェクトの [`stream()` メソッド](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream) によって返される [`ReadableStream` インターフェース](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) を使えば所望の動作が実現できます。

簡単に処理の流れを説明すると、まず [`getReader()` メソッド](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) によって [`ReadableStreamDefaultReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader) を取得して、そのオブジェクトの [`read` メソッド](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read) に、ストリームから得られた部分データ（チャンク）を扱う関数を渡す形になります。

以下に簡単なテスト用のコードを示します。これは、ファイルを逐次読み込みしてコンソールに出力するだけのものです。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Readable stream test</title>
<script>
function doRead() {
    let file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    let stream = file.stream();
    let reader = stream.getReader();
    let chunkId = 0;
    reader.read().then(function doChunk({value, done}) {
        if (done) {
            console.log("Read done.");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Chunk #" + chunkId + " (size = " + value.length + "):",
                    value);
        ++chunkId;
        return reader.read().then(doChunk);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Readable stream test</h1>
<p>読み込むファイルを選択: <input type="file" id="file"></p>
<p>読み込みを開始: <input type="button" value="Read" onclick="doRead()"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

resultという変数を用意してonprogressのイベントが発生するたびに保存しておくのはどうでしょうか？
また、この方法だとonprogressが発火するまでに15~25MB程度の文字列を読み込みます。これは5秒程度で読み込める大きさになります。

```
    <script>
        // <input type="file" id="file"/>を想定
        var file = document.getElementById('file');
        // File APIに対応しているか確認
        if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            function loadLocalImage(e) {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                var fileData = e.target.files[0];
                let result = []
                fileReader.onprogress = ( event )=>{
                    //ここで途中経過を保持
                    result.push(event.target.result)
                    if ( event.loaded > 100000 )
                        fileReader.abort();
                }
                fileReader.onabort = ( event )=>{
                    //resultに途中まで読み込んだデータが配列で格納されている
                    //joinすることで配列から文字列になる
                    //これが中断した場合のそれまでに読み込んだ成果物
                    console.log(result.join("\n"))
                }
                fileReader.onload = (event)=>{
                    console.log(result.join("\n"))
                }
                fileReader.readAsText( e.target.files[0] );
            }
            file.addEventListener('change', loadLocalImage, false);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: 残念ながら、標準では FileReader の result プロパティは読み込みが完了するまで null であるとされており、このコードはブラウザ依存の動作となると思います。 FileReader の onprogress イベントは主にプログレスバーを表示するためのもののようです。

Comment: ブラウザ依存であることは知りませんでした。私がテストした環境はChromeの最新版です。IEなどでは動かないかもしれないですね。

Comment: 手元で確認したところ、Firefox では読み込み完了前は result プロパティが null となっていました。